# SQL - Convert INT to Date (33 is 01-01-1950)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, data-conversion

I have database with dates in INT. I've tried to figure out a way to convert them to readable date but had no luck. The starting date is **33 = '01-01-1950'**.

I couldn't find formula to convert the INT to date, but I've managed to create an excel table that helped me to know the dates and it goes like the following:

[image: dbDate_table]

*All months have 31 days and starts at '0' Day

I'd like to know if there is a way to convert it in simpler way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, that looks painful. `DATEFROMPARTS` and `MOD` are going to be required.  You may be better off with a table with a DateSerial column and Date - if you already have it in excel, and don’t feel comfortable doing modular arithmetic in T-SQL, you might consider importing the data table from Excel.

Comment: Why 31-01-1950 is represented in two dbdates  in the image ?

Comment: Looking at your excel table you have 2 `dbDate` that represent same date, it is better you create that excel as a table in the database and you reference that. After that consider adding a `DATE` column in your table that store the date and not as integer

Comment: What will be the date for 94 (month 2 day 31)? Should all the days after the last day of month fall into that last day?

Comment: @VenkataramanR I'm using DATE() function to get the date and this is how it decided to read it. I have not test what the system would read it as 31-01-1950 or 01-02-1950, but I had to go with 0 as day `DD` in the start of each month other wise `dbDate` won't match the system date

Comment: @astentx 94 would actually be (month 2 day 30) and that would be 02-03-1950 according to my Excel table, but the system won't read it since 94 should actually be 30-02-1950 and no such date is existed.

Comment: @Muad96 Can you provide the logic how to deal with days after the last day of month? I've asked this question of course for the reason "no such date is existed", because you didn't provided a way to treat not real dates.

Answer (score 2):

Not too difficult to do in SQL Server, just use the `DATEADD` function twice - once to get your baseline date, and once again to add the integer onto that in days:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(
        DAY,
        dayNumber,
        DATEADD(DAY, -33, '1950-01-01') -- This gets the baseline '0' int to date value
    ) AS intToDate
FROM (
    SELECT 33 AS dayNumber
    UNION SELECT 34 AS dayNumber
) a
```

Output:

```
1950-01-01 00:00:00.000
1950-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me. I've checked one of the dates `28866` and this would be `02-05-2019`. Using your method I'm getting `2028-12-10 00:00:00.000`

Comment: How are you getting it as a 2019 date? There are 365 days per year (aside from leap years). 28866 / 365 = 79. 79 + 1950 = 2029.

Comment: @Muad96 I suspect there is an issue with your Excel formula. Feel free to post it here and I'll take a look

Comment: @e-i-pi I know that it doesn't make since and that's what I'm trying to figure out. My Excel formula/Table is working fine as far as I know, I've tested couple of times against the system generated transactions and I'm getting the correct date from my Excel table. I've posted this Q hoping that this type of date format would be something known and could be converted with SQL function, but it looks like they are using their own format :/

Comment: @Muad96 Uh yeah I'm not downloading a linked file even from Dropbox. Are you able to post the Excel formula you are using?

Comment: @e-i-pi Sure, I'm using `=DATE(D2,C2,B2)`on `Date (E)` column. The rest (A B C D) columns are values

Comment: @Muad96 it looks like your source data is fundamentally corrupted. Looking at your original post, every month has a zero day and goes up to 31. That makes 32 date records per month, or 384 date records per year. Even with that, your 28866 figure should come out to the year 2025.The only way you can get it to 2019 is if you have a 0 month as well, which would make 416 records per year.